# How can you mark your own sent messages in a chat as spam in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I read that is not possible to delete sent messages in Facebook here:[How can I delete Facebook messages sent to other users?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52532/how-can-i-delete-facebook-messages-sent-to-other-users), but an answer there says that there's a work around like this: "mark the message as Spam or Abuse (in Actions), then delete it from your messages, and disable/deactivate your account".

I tried this but there's not a option to mark my own messages as spam, when I go to the all-chats interface, when I select a conversation with a friend there's a action menu that let me mark "something" as spam (I believe that's the whole conversation that's fine by me) but I don't know if this would work since I believe that I would be marking as spam their messages and not mine, so if I press that button I think that I would be marking their messages as spam so they would be still able to watch and read my messages.

So how this work-around works if I can't mark my own messages as spam before deleting them. I know that this trick work since I have a few conversation when a yellow rectangle appears instead of my friend messages saying that the messages was marked as spam even knowing that I didn't marked their messages as spam.

Answer (score 1):

Open you conversation in chat, on top of you will see gear symbol click on that and click on option **Report Spam or Abuse**, select an option from this and mark it as spam. When you mark this conversation as spam. All the message you have sent to other person will mark as spam and that person will not be able to read your messages in his/her inbox, but what that person has sent to you will be readable for him/her in his/her inbox.

Summary is after marking spam or abusive your messages will not be readable to that person.

Comment: I read an article about what happens when you report a conversation as spam or abuse all the conversation is read by the Facebook staff to determine if it's true, so since the conversations that I want to erase are not spam they are normal conversations I believe that they are not going to be deleted, also if I do that  am I causing problems to my friends? since I'm reporting spam but it's not really spam, do my friends receive a notification if I report the conversation?

Comment: I have not read any this kind of article that Facebook staff is going to read message. And I dont think it is true. No your friend will not get any notification.

Comment: this is the article that I told you https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-safety/what-happens-after-you-click-report/432670926753695/  are those some other different kinds of reports? because it says spam in the diagram that's inside the article

Comment: Does reporting a message as SPAM actually stop the receiver from seeing a message/messages from you?

Answer (score -2):

No. I tested it after I  post a message to my friends with some information I mistakenly included. I marked as a spam, the message disappeared on my end but remain on my friends end and they can still see the message. I truly wish I can un-send my message though.

Answer (score -2):

You didn't mark it as spam then. This method is fail proof. It is important to note that you should deactivate your account for at least three days if you want more than photos to be inaccessible. It takes about three to five days for texts to be removed. The photos become inaccessible immediately. On your phone, to start, you have to go into Facebook Messenger and then hold down on the thread you want to mark as spam and then select "Mark as Spam."

Answer (score -2):

I personally know this works somehow... Years ago I had a bit of a back and fourth with a reality TV star. Now those messages on my end come up as “Spam” a box with “this message contained spam”. Everything this guy sent me is gone. I tried to do the same just as a test with my messages and did not get the same result but also did not deactivate or delete my account.