# When marking Facebook messages as spam do I have to deactivate my account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, spam-prevention

When marking Facebook messages as spam  do I have to deactivate my account right after I report them or if I do it within 24 hours does it still work to delete my sent messages?

Comment: Why would you need to deactivate your account after reporting another person's messages as spam?

Comment: It is what i read in another thread..

Comment: Can you link to it?

Comment: That's the stupidest thing I've heard this week. Someone's pulling your leg.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/111533/186802

Answer (score 1):

**NO.** You don't have to deactivate your account, even you don't need to logout right after reporting a message as spam or anything else.

See the Facebook Help Center:
[Reporting a Message](https://www.facebook.com/help/118100101665319/)
[Report a threatening Facebook message](https://www.facebook.com/help/1709360766019559?helpref=about_content).
[Reporting Conversations](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/1165699260192280/)